# PHPUnit: how to test HTML structure output

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to test a HTML structure render.

I saw this method: https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertTag

...But on the last version, it's obsolete.

What is now the best practice for this kind of verification ?

Best regards.

Comment: Since you tagged this Laravel then you can check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests . You can also use the [browser-kit testing library](https://github.com/laravel/browser-kit-testing) which used to be part of Laravel but not is a separate package.

Comment: I think you want to use any of [these methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#available-assertions), you should be using `$response->assertSee()` or similar.

Comment: thanks. Finally, I did something pretty simple:

    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($blocks_html);

    $this->assertTrue($dom->getElementById('MYID')->hasAttributes());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were deprecated in 2014:

> https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1292

The new versions are in progress:

> - https://github.com/lstrojny/phpunit-dom-assertions
> - https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit-dom-assertions